# Bulk removing Twitter followers

Tags: twitter

A charity I help had its Twitter account compromised and it was used to spam. It was also mass followed by thousands of fake accounts who started retweeting the spam. The offending tweets have been removed but the account still has thousands of fake followers.

Is there a simple way to bulk remove/block followers who followed an account after a certain date, or at least bulk remove/block obviously fake followers? I did search and found some console scripts but they are years out of date and no longer work.

We'd rather not have to delete the account and start again, or have to manually "remove this follower" one by one, or use one of the paid services.

Answer (score 0):

The API endpoint for blocking accounts is POST /2/users/:id/blocking | Docs | Twitter Developer Platform 1 and you can call this 50 times in 15 min. There is no way to differentiate legitimate from spam accounts however - that is entirely up to you.

There’s no way to know the exact date someone followed your account, but GET /2/users/:id/followers | Docs | Twitter Developer Platform returns results in order, so newest ones are first.